# Add status info to systemd's status output

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, startup

I'm writing a systemd script for a backup software client called Retrospect. This software doesn't follow any kind of typical linux ways of doing things. Getting a status from the program means running `retrocpl -status`. This has information that is both important and not currently gathered by systemd automatically. Can it be added to the status output somehow?

```
[Service] 
ExecStart=/usr/local/retrospect/client/retroclient        
ExecStop=/usr/local/retrospect/client/retrocpl -stop
Restart=on-failure RestartSec=60s
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 which has systemd 229.

```
$ systemd --version
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

EDIT: Removed errant information that Wieland pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: The ExecStatus you're looking at is a data structure, not a command. AFAIK systemd doesn't support what you want, even in version 231.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the clarification, even if it does squelch my hope a little bit. :-)

Answer (score 2):

systemd has a protocol where applications can send messages to the service manager, that get displayed in the output of `systemctl status`.  It has to be implemented in the application itself for best results.  The application has to proactively *transmit* status notifications.

### Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2010). [`sd_notify()`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html). systemd manual pages. Freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering (2010). [`systemd-notify`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-notify.html). systemd manual pages. Freedesktop.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[Adoption limited by deliberate crippling of servers that nominally *have* adopted the protocols](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html#CrippledAdoption)" *Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[using a synchronous protocol when pulling client credentials](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html#SynchronousProtocol)" *Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: The https://jdebp.eu links are broken - could you explain the issues with using the protocol? or help find other links?